# Bigquery SQL - WHERE IN Col Value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

so i have reference table (table A) like this

```
| cust_id | prod |
|   1     | A, B |
|   2     | C, D, E|
```

This reference table will be joined by transaction history like table (table B)

```
| trx_id | cust_id | prod | amount
|   1    |    1    | A    |  10
|   2    |    1    | B    |  5
|   3    |    1    | C    |  1
|   4    |    1    | D    |  6
```

i want to get sumup value of table b amount, but the list of products is only obtained from table A.
i tried something like this but doesn't work

```
SELECT A.cust_id
, SUM(B.amount) AS amount
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B ON A.cust_id = B.cust_id
AND B.prod IN(A.prod)
GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm . . . Try splitting the `prod` and join on that:

```
SELECT A.cust_id, SUM(B.amount) AS amount
FROM A CROSS JOIN
     UNNEST(SPLIT(a.prod, ', ')) p JOIN
     B
     ON A.cust_id = B.cust_id AND B.prod = p
GROUP BY 1;
```

Note:  Storing multiple values in a string is a really bad idea.  You can use a separate junction table (one row per customer and product) or use an array.

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select cust_id, 
  sum(if(b.prod in unnest(split(a.prod, ', ')), amount, 0)) as amount
from `project.dataset.tableB` b
join `project.dataset.tableA` a
using(cust_id)
group by cust_id
```

Also, note: for **BigQuery** - in general - storing multiple values in a string is a really good idea. :o)
See [Denormalize data whenever possible](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-input#denormalize_data_whenever_possible) for more on this